# Enabling sorting for a column using DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I am having a html table getting populated using JSON by an ajax call as follows -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my_url",
    data: JSON.stringify(result),
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset= Shift-JIS",
    success: function (response) {
        glResp = response;
        populateTable(glResp);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        //alert("Error!!");
    }
});
```

The function used for populating the table is as follows -

```
function populateTable(finalObject) {
    var obj = finalObject;

    var headers1 = ['Name', 'ID', 'Job', 'Salary','JoiningDate'];
    var table = $("<table id='my-table' />");
    var columns = headers1;
    columns.unshift('');
    var columnCount = columns.length;
    var row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));

    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            var headerCell = $("<th><input type='button' id='sort'></th>");
            row.append(headerCell);
        }
        else {
            var headerCell = $("<th/>");
            headerCell.html([columns[i]]);
            row.append(headerCell);
        }
    }

    $.each(obj, function (i, obj) {
        $row = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>' + obj.Name + '</td><td>' + obj.ID+ '</td><td>' + obj.Job + '</td><td>' + obj.Salary + '</td><td>'+ obj.JoiningDate+'</td></tr>';
        table.append(row);
    });

    var dvTable = $("#dvCSV");
    dvTable.html("");
    dvTable.append(table);
}
```

Now I want to enable sorting for only two columns - ID & JoiningDate using DataTable plugin. I tried to understand the api but everytime something or the other problem came up. **(E.g. for ID = M981-01) (E.g. for date: 2016-10-24)** Can anyone help me to implement DataTable plugin or any other suitable approach to enable sort with respect to ID and JoiningDate?

Comment: Can you show how you tried to enable and specify sort ?